# Null pointer exception while parsing JSON in Android

Tags: android, json

I am getting Null pointer exception while parsing JSON on Android.

This is the JSON I want to parse:

```
[{"value":"91.84","timestamp":"2012-10-11 14:12:13"}]
```

Here is the way I am parsing it:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = null;
HttpResponse response;
BufferedReader reader;
JSONObject jObject;
String aJsonString1;
String aJsonString2;


public class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url is written here");
        // Depends on your web service
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);      
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

         for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject oneObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Pulling items from the array
                String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("value");
                String oneObjectsItem2 = oneObject.getString("timestamp");
            }

         aJsonString1  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("value");
         aJsonString2  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("timestamp");


        return aJsonString1;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("JSON",e.getMessage() + "  " + e);
        }           
        return null; // Error case

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(aJsonString1);

        if(aJsonString1==null){
            textView.setText("nothing to show");
        }

    }
```

And this is the stack trace I get:

```
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at com.example.ayasms.MainActivity$ReadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:176)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at com.example.ayasms.MainActivity$ReadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-26 15:37:40.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     ... 4 more
```

Can you see what might be the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first idea that comes to my mind is that I'd like you to write code which checks for the success of operations which can fail, and output a respective log message if they fail. ;)

Comment: Don't debug nullpointers by posting here :p You can always figure it out yourself if you learn how. First thing to check is the line number.

Comment: OMG why did you just copy pasted previous answer? Its not `result` its `sb.toString()` in your code

Comment: There are lots of line numbers here. Which one I should look at?

Comment: hehe=D @Stan, you are right I am too much reckless, my pardon. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: did you just asked the same question 3 times ?

Answer (score 3):

The String object `result`, which you're passing into the `JSONArray` constructor, is `null`. You are never changing it from its initial value.

Comment: Thats right careful eyes here! I should pass "response" into JSONArray constructor right?

Comment: I think you probably want to pass in `sb.toString()`, but really you know more than I do about what it *should* be doing!

Comment: No! Cause you have 19.7k rep and I have 5! I am a newbei, so actually you can know more about my code than me:) Thanks for your help.